# Can Drupal change the template used based on a file extension in the url?

Tags: drupal, file-extension

I am using Drupal 6.16 with a number of modules installed. I was trying to find out if there is a way to change the output of a node when a different file extension is added to the url. For example:

```
http://example.com/drupal?q=foo/bar - returns a normal drupal node
http://example.com/drupal?q=foo/bar.xml - returns xml output of the node
```

Is this even possible with Drupal? Do I have to hack the core code to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I fixed this.

1. Add the [custom_url_rewrite_inbound](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/custom_url_rewrite_inbound/6) function to check for incoming request ending with .xml. If it finds a request ending with .xml it strips that off, so that the correct data can be located by the rest of the drupal machinery. It also sets 'subsite_xml_request' to true so that the appropriate theme template can be used later.

   ```
   function custom_url_rewrite_inbound (&$result, $path, $path_language) {
     if(preg_match('/\.xml$/', $path)) {
       $search = preg_replace('/^(.*)\.xml$/', "$1", $path);
       if ($src = drupal_lookup_path('source', $search, $path_language)) {
         $_REQUEST['xml_request'] = true;
         $result = $src;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Modify the [phptemplate_preprocess_page](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/phptemplate_preprocess_page/6) function in your template.php to add additional '-xml' templates.

   ```
   function phptemplate_preprocess_page(&$vars) {   
     if ($_REQUEST['xml_request']) {
       if (module_exists('path')) {
         $path = str_replace('/edit','',$_GET['q']);
         $alias = drupal_get_path_alias($path);
         if ($alias != $_GET['q']) {
           $template_filename = 'page';
           foreach (explode('/', $alias) as $path_part) {
             $template_filename = $template_filename . '-' . $path_part;
             $vars['template_files'][] = $template_filename . '-xml';
           }
           $vars['template_files'][] = 'page-xml';
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. Create the required page-xml.tpl.php

Comment: In Drupal 6, phptemplate_preprocess_page should be renamed to YOURTHEME_preprocess_page.

Comment: Great find! And you don't have to modify the core code to use it. I'm going to add this to my growing list of "might need this in the future" drupal functions.

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to [hack the core](http://drupal.org/node/144376) code. There are probably several contributed modules that can do this for you.

To output an XML version of a node, check out the [Views Bonus Pack](http://drupal.org/project/views_bonus) module, which extends the Views module. It has basic export capabilities, including CSV, TXT, DOC, and XML. The documentation is brief, but there is a README.txt file in the views_bonus/export/ directory that gives the basic steps for creating a feed in a view that will output XML.

You can set the path for the feed, so while I don't believe the `.xml` extension will work, you could set up a path with an additional component like this:

```
http://example.com/drupal?q=foo/bar      <-- normal output
http://example.com/drupal?q=foo/bar/xml  <-- XML output
```

To change the template file that is used for a node based on the path, you can use a [preprocess function](http://drupal.org/node/223430) in your template.php file to add a [template suggestion](http://drupal.org/node/223440) based on the path. This takes a bit more understanding of how the template files work, but ultimately you'll have more control of the output than you will with a view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Having the .xml extension is pretty core to what I am trying to achieve, so I will have to keep looking.

Comment: Is the .xml extension on the path important or is the important part the .xml extension on the resulting file?